# PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter addAttachment not working

Tags: python, pypdf

Based on https://programtalk.com/python-examples/PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter/, example 2, I try to to add an attachment into a PDF file.

Here is my code I am trying to run:

```py
import os

from django.conf import settings

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

...

doc = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "../media/SC/myPDF.pdf")

reader = PdfFileReader(doc, "rb")

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)

writer.addAttachment("The filename to display", "The data in the file")

with open(doc, "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

When I run this code, I get: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

If I replace

```
with open(doc, 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

by:

```
with open(doc, 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(b'fp')
```

I get this error: "'bytes' object has no attribute 'write'".

And if I try:

```
with open(doc, 'w') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I get this error: "write() argument must be str, not bytes"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: People coming here might want to read the [official PyPDF2 docs about adding attachments](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html#attachments)

Answer (score 1):

Second argument in addAttachment has to be a byte-like object. You can do that by encoding the string:

```
writer.addAttachment("The filename to display", "The data in the file".encode())
```